# Using JQuery to self-submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to use JQuery to submit a form on the same page within a DIV.  It works fine, however whenever I submit the form, it reloads the form script.  For example

add-album.php contains the form and PHP logic 
index.php contains include("add-album.php") within the DIV tag.

While on index.php, I will fill in the form details and click 'submit' which then redirects to add-album.php.  How can I prevent this from happening?

JQUERY Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").load(this.href);
    });
});
```

PHP _SELF form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you want it to take you after submitting?

Answer (score 0):

The action of the form is the address of the current script because you set it to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.  It's a little tricky, though - it's going to be the script that runs that code, which may or may not be the one loaded directly by the browser.

This means that when you submit, either manually or with jQuery, you are going to send the data and request to whatever corresponds to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.  If you want to arrive somewhere else, you probably want to set the action of the form to be something besides this "current script" value.  In this case, add-album.php is the file that is calling `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>`, so you get add-album.php in the action.

To see what I mean, look at the rendered code of the index.php page. You will see that the form tag renders with `action="add-album.php"` or something similar.  That's why add-album.php loads when you submit.  You may find that setting the action with a static value is what you want.  You left out one important detail - where do you want to send the form data?

Comment: In essence, I want it all to stay on the same page.  The PHP logic creates directories, and adds an image to one of them.  It's not submitting data to be read.  I think the best way to describe it is how this site works,  I can click submit or "Save Edits" on the right hand side, and rather than going to another page, or loading up "Thank You"  I just want the "Album created" to appear below the form; which it does, but I don't want it to redirect.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `action="/index.php"` or something similar?  Is there a good reason to pull the form functionality out to add-album.php?  If add-album.php needs to do the processing work, can you redirect to index.php with header() after processing is done?

Comment: I have tried that already and it just resets the page back to the landing page.  This is frustrating lol.  I know I'm probably overly complicating things, but I'm just starting out with PHP again for about 5 years+

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent form from submitting:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: He wants it to submit - read his first sentence.  It's the destination after submit that's the problem.